# Computer won't turn off after hibernation

Tags: windows-xp

For long time I have been using hibernation instead of shutdown. I do normal shutdowns maybe twice a week if not less.  After hibernation I always power off computer (from UPS button) because USB devices stays working.

I don't know what happened but now my PC isn't shutting down after falling to hibernation. It justs restarts. But restarts with delay of 1/2 seconds (not sure). I don't know what's wrong. Problem from hardware level or OS problem? Maybe it's because of overclocking that I failed (computer just froze up and I was forced to reset CMOS)? Also no problems were indicated by Memtest86+.

```
Windows XP PRO SP3 with latest updates of course
Motherboard - Gigabyte GA-945PL-S3
CPU - DualCore Intel Core 2 Duo E4300, 1800 MHz (9 x 200)
Video card - Gigabyte GeForce 7200 GS
```

**Edit**

***14.12.11***

I noticed that computer does turn off, but not the motherboard. I can hear that HDD shudowns off.

Comment: Have you tried a System Restore to go back to a point when it was working?  Have you tried hibernating without any peripherals attached?

Answer (score 1):

The manual for your motherboard can be [found here](http://download.gigabyte.asia/FileList/Manual/motherboard_manual_ga-945pl-s3_e.pdf)
Page 38 shows that the default setting for ACPI suspend type is S1/POS. Try changing this to S3/STR and see if that fixes the issue. This would have been caused by your reset of the CMOS.

For reference, [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface) explains the different S states.

Comment: Nope. Didn't work. :( What's wrong?

Comment: @roberts
I just looked at your profile and see that you do not have the machine in question listed, so I can't tell how much RAM you have. If you have 1GB of RAM, [this Hotfix] (http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=414) may apply. There are a number of other things to attempt [on this page] (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907477) that may help. Also, if you can check your event log and see if there are any error messages that may relate to this problem?

Comment: Yes I have only 1 gig of RAM. And I don't have Service Pack 2, I have SP3 - hotfix failed.

Comment: Did you try any of the things on the second page I linked? Did you check the event log to see if there is anything listed that might apply to this issue?

Comment: Something with Windows XP...